# How to redefine tag of parents dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Suppose there is an image Nginx described by the following Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:stretch
.....

And there is an image of SomeServer described:
FROM Nginx
...

Can I somehow change parents FROM ubuntu:stretch to ubuntu:bionic?

Comment: yes. you can change the parent image.

Comment: You have to re-run `docker build` on each image in the stack, and there are potentially incompatibilities from the version upgrade, but beyond that, nothing’s stopping you.  (You can’t change the parent underneath the intermediate image without rebuilding it.)